# Adding prefix to the namespace using XSLT

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I have the requirement to add the prefix to the namespace.

Input XML:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <ProductMovementReport Version="5.0" xmlns="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:0">
            <Header>
                <ThisDocumentIdentifier>
                    <DocumentIdentifier>868</DocumentIdentifier>
                </ThisDocumentIdentifier>
            </Header>

        </ProductMovementReport>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

I also need to change the value of the Version ="'5'" which I am able to get successfully.

Below the is the desire output.

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <urn1:ProductMovementReport Version="4.0" xmlns:urn1="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0">
            <urn1:Header>
                <urn1:ThisDocumentIdentifier>
                    <urn1:DocumentIdentifier>868</urn1:DocumentIdentifier>
                </urn1:ThisDocumentIdentifier>

            </urn1:Header>

        </urn1:ProductMovementReport>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

I have written the code for this and everything is working except the namespace part is not getting change. I guess I am missing something in the template match.

Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Version' ">
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="'4.0'"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="urn1:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the link in case I missed anything http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpP.

I am very close to solving it except namespace part.

Can anyone please point me where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match for `match="*"` is matching all elements regardless of namespace. Try narrowing the scope by testing the namespace URI.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:0']">
        <xsl:element name="urn1:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@Version">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:text>4.0</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <urn1:ProductMovementReport xmlns:urn1="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:4:0" Version="4.0">
      <urn1:Header>
         <urn1:ThisDocumentIdentifier>
            <urn1:DocumentIdentifier>868</urn1:DocumentIdentifier>
         </urn1:ThisDocumentIdentifier>
      </urn1:Header>
   </urn1:ProductMovementReport>
</soapenv:Body>
```